# Get data distribution given a dataframe R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I would like to "see" which distribution my data follow.

My data represent the entering passengers at 10 bus stops for 1 month at the same time each day.

```
Date    Stop.1    Stop.2    Stop.3    Stop.4    Stop.5  ...
2-9    3    26    11    3    0    
3-9    2    44    23    0    12    
4-9    26    16    0    0    4    
...
```

My goal is to understand the distribution of the "entering" passengers at each stop so that I can create a simulation for the arrivals at each Stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Density Plot

You can plot the probability density function to let you "see" the distribution. Assuming `df` is a dataframe containing the information:

```
d <- density(df$Stop.1) # returns the density data for Stop 1.

plot(d) # plots the results
```

## Summary statistics

Or you can use the `basicStats` function from the `fBasics` package to give some useful summary statistics.

```
library(fBasics)

basicStats(df)
```